# how to open list of video links in JW player 6 (mp4 format / light box)

Tags: jwplayer6

I have a webpage which opens .flv video files in light box (top_up-min.js/modal). Now i am trying to open the .mp4 version of same video files using JW player 6 in a light box.

The code i tried is working to open a video in lightbox [jquery.jwbox.js ] and suggested code opens a hidden div as a lightbox .But i have below issues

1.After clicking the video ,click anywhere else other than “close button” the video still closes. 
In IE 8 or above , even after closing the video ,you can hear the audio. It only stops when you refresh the page .

Does anyone already using this have any fix for this?

2.Is there any other jquery light that can be used for JW player (mp4 format)

Thanks

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jwbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jwbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key = "key";</script>

<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//this function i tried to close the video because the    existing jquery one 
closes  video even when u touch outside the box.but its throwing js error.

function fnClose() {       
       document.getElementById('jwbox_hidden').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('jwbox_background').style.display = 'none';
       jwplayer().stop(true);
       return false;
   }
   function loadVideo(myFile,title) {
       document.getElementById("videoTitle").innerHTML = title;

       jwplayer("player").setup({              
           file: myFile,
           width: '640',
           height: '480',
           volume: 100,
           autostart: true,              
           primary: "flash"
       });
   }
    </script>   
 </head>
<body>
<p>
 Click the link to display a JW player with a video in the JW Box.


</p>
    <div class="jwbox">
         <ul> <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadVideo('http://wpc.2A70.edgecastcdn.net/002A70/CareerVideos/45-2092.01.mp4','Nursery Workers');">Nursery Workers</a></li></ul>
         <ul> <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadVideo('http://wpc.2A70.edgecastcdn.net/002A70/CareerVideos/15-1021.00.mp4','Computer Programmers');">Computer Programmers</a></li></ul>
         <ul> <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadVideo('http://wpc.2A70.edgecastcdn.net/002A70/CareerVideos/39-9011.00.mp4','Child Care Workers');">Child Care Workers</a></li></ul>


  <div class="jwbox_hidden" id="jwbox_hidden">
     <div  class="jwbox_content">
     <label id="videoTitle" class="te_title">          </label>
      <a class="te_close_link" style="display: block;" onclick="fnClose();" ></a>
    <div id="player"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this might not be the answer you're precisely looking for but it worked when I tested it. I haven't found the precise cause of the problem. This is a hacky workaround.

If you look in jwbox.js there's a try catch block like this:

```
            try {
            $.jwbox.player.sendEvent("STOP");
            $.jwbox.player = null;
        } catch (err) { }
```

I added your fnClose() into the catch block:

```
            try {
            $.jwbox.player.sendEvent("STOP");
            $.jwbox.player = null;
        } catch (err) { fnClose() }
```

Alternatively, this seems to perform faster:

```
            try {
            fnClose();
            $.jwbox.player.sendEvent("STOP");
            $.jwbox.player = null;
        } catch (err) {  }
```

That at least invokes fnClose() when if sendEvent("STOP") fails, which is, I believe, the root of the problem.

Hope that helps, sorry this is my first StackOverflow answer :)
-Pablo